# How to make a unique SQL query instead of using intermediate tables? (correlated subquery?)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I've been coding for sometime but this is genuinely the first time I can't find an answer to my specific question and have to ask my own "version of it".

I'm working on a database regarding schools, classes, gardens, plants and measurements (rilevazioni) on those plants, and I have to make a query that selects, for each school, the person or the class who made the most measurements (rilevazioni), so I started doing it by creating a table that counts, for each school the number of relevations made by each person related to that school and by each class, and then I used another query to select from this intermediate table only "what I need" so the person (or class) that made the maximum number of measurements and their classname (if they're a class)/italian fiscal code (if they're a person), but how can I do that without creating an intermediate table?

I don't think it is really efficient that way and I'm aware it's a naive approach of doing it but it's the only one I could think of

```
CREATE TABLE tabella_intermedia 
AS
    SELECT 
        scuola.nome AS nome_scuola, scuola.provincia AS provincia_scuola, 
        scuola.codmec AS codicemeccanografico_scuola,
        rilevazioni_per_persona.effettua_codfiscale AS persona_in_questione, 
        rilevazioni_per_classe.nomeclasse AS classe_in_questione,
        rilevazioni_per_persona.count AS numero_rilevazioni_effettuato_dalla_persona,
        rilevazioni_per_classe.count AS numero_rilevazioni_effettuato_dalla_classe
    FROM 
        scuola 
    NATURAL JOIN 
        RifIniz AS ScuolaRif
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT rilevazione.effettua_codfiscale, COUNT(*) AS count 
         FROM rilevazione 
         GROUP BY rilevazione.effettua_codfiscale) AS rilevazioni_per_persona ON scuolaRif.codfiscale = rilevazioni_per_persona.effettua_codfiscale
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT classe.codmec, classe.nomeclasse, COUNT(*) AS count
         FROM rilevazione 
         JOIN classe ON rilevazione.effettua_codmec = classe.codmec 
                     AND rilevazione.effettua_nome = classe.nomeclasse
         GROUP BY classe.nomeclasse, classe.codmec) AS rilevazioni_per_classe ON scuola.codmec = rilevazioni_per_classe.codmec
    GROUP BY 
        scuola.nome, scuola.codmec, 
        numero_rilevazioni_effettuato_dalla_persona, 
        numero_rilevazioni_effettuato_dalla_classe, 
        persona_in_questione, classe_in_questione;


SELECT DISTINCT ON (codicemeccanografico_scuola)
    nome_scuola,
    provincia_scuola,
    codicemeccanografico_scuola,
    CASE 
        WHEN COALESCE(numero_rilevazioni_effettuato_dalla_persona, 0) >= COALESCE(numero_rilevazioni_effettuato_dalla_classe, 0) /*COALESCE ci serve per trattare i valori nulli come zeri, invece che come sconosciuti, perché altrimenti ogni confronto tra un numero e un NULL darebbe NULL, e ciò non ci va bene*/
            THEN persona_in_questione /*in caso l'entità che ha effettuato più rilevazioni per la data scuola sia una persona inseriremo il suo codicefiscale qua dentro */
        ELSE classe_in_questione /*in caso tale entità sia una classe inseriremo il nome della classe*/
    END AS enità_che_ha_effettuato_più_rilevazioni,
    greatest(numero_rilevazioni_effettuato_dalla_classe, 
    numero_rilevazioni_effettuato_dalla_persona) AS numero_rilevazioni
FROM 
    tabella_intermedia
ORDER BY 
    codicemeccanografico_scuola, 
    GREATEST(numero_rilevazioni_effettuato_dalla_classe, numero_rilevazioni_effettuato_dalla_persona) DESC;
```

I tried many ways found online but never was able to return the expected output (I have 14 schools in my DB and by using this "naive method" is the only way I could return 14 tuples, and, for each school, the name of the class or the fiscal code of the person who made the most measurements)

Comment: What is the intermediate table here? While I havent worked on postgresql, does GROUPING SET and CTE help here?

Comment: yeah I tried with CTE but it didn't work, how would you advise to do it with CTE? (I am saying "intermediate table" to refer to the table I created with the first select query, ideally I would like to use a query that reaches my goal of returning the expected output without having to create table, from which I take only the tuples I need)

Comment: Please update your question with sample data (formatted as tables), and the result you want to achieve based on that data

Comment: did using `with tablella_intermedia as` in place of  `create table tabella_intermedia as` not work? ref: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-cte/

Comment: no wayyy you saved me bro thanks so much, so by doing this the table is created "temporary", right? And thus all the piece of code can be considered a unique query?

Comment: I suspect there is more that could be done over just using a CTE. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's the fastest way to get an efficient & reliable solution.